# How I can return value from Thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a bulb and in manual they say that I need send request via UDP. So I create class that send and receive that info what I need. When I try send/obtain request directly from main, studio say that I can't use network from main thread so I put my send/obtain methods to threads. And now I can't understand how I can return any value from thread. Please help. Thanks.

```
package com.bulbs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class udpHelper {
    public void sendRequest(final String host, final String command, final int port) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                byte[] message = command.getBytes();
                try {
                    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, address, port);
                    DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
                    dsocket.send(packet);
                    dsocket.close();
                    System.out.println("Sent");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }


    public void receiveRequest(final int port) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                    while (true) {
                        dsocket.receive(packet);
                        String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
                        System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + " : " + msg);
                        packet.setLength(buffer.length);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```